# mp4 video file with gps location

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg, gps

I had a understanding that there is no official support to insert gps location metadata into .mp4 files. However, I see a gps location metadata inserted into the video file while I was using my Sony Z2 with geotagging on. ffmpeg was able to detect the metadata after exporting the same file to my laptop. Anyone knows if  there a new interface method or api declared for such purpose in andriod ndk?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using https://www.bento4.com to transfer GPS information that got lost during re-encoding of videos using ffmpeg.

Android phone stores it in the [©xyz] atom, which is a member of  [udta] atom, which in turn is a member of the [moov] atom. iPhone or iPad stores it somewhere inside the numerous atoms that are part of the [meta] atom, which is a member of the [moov] atom . This is what these two options looks like in Mediainfo:
©xyz : 
com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709  :

The ©xyz coordinates can be copied from input.mp4 to output.mp4 using those commands:
mp4extract moov/udta/©xyz input.mp4 temp.txt
mp4edit --insert moov:temp.txt output.mp4 output_gps.mp4

You could also copy the entire [udta] atom along with all the information that are in it.

Note: the copyright sign is not part of the US codepage 437, a batch file containing ©xyz will fail. Change to code page that contain the copyright symbol first using chcp 1250.

The com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709 coordinates can be copied from input.mp4 to output.mp4 by copying the entire meta atom along with the atom that contains the location (and others) using those commands:
mp4extract moov/meta input.mp4 temp.txt
mp4edit --insert moov:temp.txt output.mp4 output_gps.mp4

To get an overview over all available atoms and their path you can run
mp4dump input.mp4

You can basically transfer any atom from input.mp4 to output.mp4, e.g. I also used it to maintain a 90 degree rotation that got lost during conversion by replacing the [tkhd] atom.